# how to pass a null as the store procedure parameter in WCF LOB adapter

Tags: wcf, biztalk

one of parameter field requires to passed as null, use WCF lob SQL adapter, how to pass a null to a store procedure parameter? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you've added the Schemas to your PROC via the Add Generated Items / Consume WCF Adapter Service, the, Proc Request schema should look as follows for a nullable proc field:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MyParam" nillable="true" type="xs:int" />
```

In your map, either use the [nil value functoid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb728021.aspx) to map, or if you are using XSLT, then you can map like so:

```
<ns0:MyProc>
  <ns0:MyParam>
    <xsl:attribute name="xsi:nil">
      <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </ns0:MyParam>
</ns0:MyProc>
```